# FFmpeg normalize damaged the file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Faced with a problem when normalizing audio in video: when normalizing using FFmpeg, the video stops playing in Firefox because  "... video is corrupted ..."
Here is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180_0003.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vcodec copy -filter:a loudnorm BigBuckBunny_320x180_0003_normalized.mp4
```

Why is this happening?

PS:
Here is the original and normalized video - https://we.tl/t-DORKCbYp3T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loudnorm filter resamples the audio to 192 kHz, and it needs to be resampled to a standard rate that players accept.

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180_0003.mp4 -c:v copy -filter:a loudnorm -ar 48000 -c:a aac BigBuckBunny_320x180_0003_normalized.mp4
```